# converting date format to eliminate time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have  a table where the date and time stamp are logged together and I want to only show the date in a 10 character output. Also I want to return as blank some dates in the field that are 01/01/1800.

The current table format is 2013-06-28 00:00:00:000
I just want the date. I was using RTRIM function but it keeps erroring out.

Thanking you in advance

Comment: When you say "show": are you referring to how the data looks in a report or on a screen?  In that case, it's usually easier to do the formatting in the report or screen itself. T-SQL is just not a good tool for doing complex formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE CONVERT(DATE, @MyValue) WHEN '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(DATE, @MyValue) END
```

Or if you prefer:

```
DECLARE @DateOnlyValue DATE
SET @DateOnlyValue = CONVERT(DATE, @MyValue)
SELECT CASE @DateOnlyValue WHEN '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE @DateOnlyValue END
```

The latter is just [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)er.

Comment: what is @myvalue suppose to be

Comment: @khan16 -- your value.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
select (case when datecol > '1800-01-01' then convert(varchar(10), datecol, 121) end)
```

This will convert the value to a string of the form YYYY-MM-DD.

This uses `NULL` for "blank".  If you want an empty string:

```
select (case when datecol > '1800-01-01'
             then convert(varchar(10), datecol, 121)
             else ''
         end)
```

This also assumes that the values with '1800-01-01' don't have a time component.  That seems reasonable for a default extreme value.

Comment: not liking the 'date' by the way I am writing this into a script

Comment: this is what I have now CASE
WHEN A.svcdt1 = '18000101'
THEN
Convert(nvarchar(20),A.SVCDT1)+'-'+Convert(nvarchar(20),A.SVCDT1)
ELSE ' ' 
END AS Service_Facility,  and getting the following output Jan  1 1800 12:00AM-Jan  1 1800 12:00AM the desired output will be only the date in this format 12/14/2012 (10 character limit) and all dates with 1800 year to be blank

Comment: @khan16 . . . `date` is a reserved word in SQL Server.  It was just there as a place holder for whatever your column name really is.  You want to use `convert()` the way specified in this answer.